# Unable to set Kubernete cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm following steps mentioned [here](https://railskey.wordpress.com/2016/05/28/installing-kubernetes-cluster-with-2-minions-on-ubuntu-to-manage-pods-and-services/) to configure kubernete cluster.But when I'm executing `kubectl get nodes` to check the status of my newly created cluster, that time I'm getting error message `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

In this link it is mentioned for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit server, but I'm using Ubuntu 16,04 64 Bit.
Can you expert please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the following commands (as a regular user) after you have initialized your cluster:

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

Follow [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44665) on GitHub if you still encounter it.

Answer (score 1):

The document your following is more then year old, its not update to date steps.

I would recommend creating cluster using the kubeadm with version v.1.7.0

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

use this configure master

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --kubernetes-version v1.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your client configuration thinks the server runs on localhost:8080 which is probably not the case.
Can you look at the `~/.kube/config` file to see what is configured there?
Also try running `kubectl --server=<SERVER_IP>:<SERVER_PORT> get nodes` and see if this helps.